# Juridicité et « judiciarité »

Tags: sens, terminologie, droit-et-justice

Quelqu'un connaîtrait-il les différences entre juridicité et « judiciarité » ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ces mots ne sont pas très courants. Aucun des deux n'est dans le *Trésor de la langue française*. Le nom *juridicité* se rapporte à l'adjectif *[juridique](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/juridique)*, et le nom *judiciarité* se rapporte à l'adjectif *[judiciaire](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/judiciaire)* ; ces deux adjectifs sont plus courants.

#### *Juridique* se rapporte au droit, à la loi.

Le [Juridictionnaire](http://www.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/juridi/index-eng.html?lang=eng&lettr=indx_catlog_j&page=886.html) canadien a une entrée bien fournie pour *juridicité*. Le sens est le même de part et d'autre de l'Atlantique.

Le *[principe de juridicité](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principe_de_l%C3%A9galit%C3%A9_en_droit_administratif_fran%C3%A7ais)* signifie que l'administration (c'est-à-dire l'État) est soumis à la loi.

> *[La juridicité des droits de solidarité en question dans le droit international des droits de l’homme](http://credof.u-paris10.fr/spip.php?article209)* : dans quelle mesure le droit international énonce des principes de solidarité.
>
> *[La juridicité de la coutume kanak](http://droitcultures.revues.org/2347)* : la façon dont les lois et règlements français prennent en compte les le droit coutumier kanak.

#### *Judiciaire* se rapporte à la Justice, l'institution qui comprend les juges, les tribunaux, etc.

Le *[principe de judiciarité](http://actu.dalloz-etudiant.fr/fileadmin/actualites/pdfs/D2008_hennion_jacquet.pdf)* énonce que les sanctions légales telles que l'emprisonnement doivent être prises par la justice.

> *[Il s’agit d’une volonté de l’exécutif et du législateur de réduire la judiciarité de la peine.](http://www.lysias-avocats.com/index.php/en/lysiasthe-firms-activity/70-conference-de-jean-pierre-mignard-l-les-grandes-questions-du-systeme-de-justice-penaler.html)* Le gouvernement veut réduire la marge qu'ont les juges dans le choix d'une peine (durée d'emprisonnement par exemple).
>
> *[cela postule un élément de « judiciarité » [...] : une conduite sociale entrerait dans le domaine du droit quand elle serait susceptible d'être soumise à un jugement](http://books.google.fr/books?id=x7YTIK5pYe4C&pg=PA38&lpg=PA38&dq=judiciarit%C3%A9&source=bl&ots=a1NXZcJnqJ&sig=kwp3pIKig2kUP1h8d-HQQ3ZiZh4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=MGlmT5uyIq-A0AX0nIWjCA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=judiciarit%C3%A9&f=false)*. La judiciarité signifie qu'il y a une institution formelle ou informelle chargée de porter un jugement sur cette conduite.

Comment: Donc la juridicité se rapporte au champ d'application et la judiciarité à la capacité d'application?

Comment: @Knu Je crois qu'il s'agit de champ d'application dans les deux cas (droit, justice), mais il se peut que je n'aie pas compris ton commentaire.

Comment: Par exemple le champs d'application d'une loi peut être défini dans  un certain type de situation ensuite sa non-conformité dans un cas particulier peut entraîner des restrictions dans son application. Est-ce plus clair?

Comment: @Knu Effectivement, on peut parler de *juridicité* pour ce qu'impose la loi et de *judiciarité* pour ce qui est laissé à l'appréciation du juge. Si ce n'est toujours pas clair, il faudrait voir le contexte.